# Converter is never called when trying to sort a HierachicalDataTemplate via CollectionViewSource and Converter

Tags: wpf, hierarchicaldatatemplate, collectionviewsource

I try to sort a HierachicalDataTemplate via CollectionViewSource and a Converter Class (CollectionViewFactoryConverter), which should be the perfect solution to be able to sort all levels of the treeview. I use a DXTreelist from DevExpress, but I assume this isn not the source of my problem.

My problem: The Converter is never triggered. I can put a breakpoint into the Convert or the ConvertBack method, but I never end up there. I can't figure it out why there is no reaction. - Can anyone help?

WPF Code:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <view:CollectionViewFactoryConverter x:Key="collectionViewFactoryConverter" />

    <local:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="templateSelector" />
    <local:ContentToTreeListNodeConverter x:Key="contentToTreeListNodeConverter"/>

    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Path=Data, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Key="cvsRoot">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="StandardTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="Template Not Found!" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="RootTemplate"
        ItemsSource="{Binding RefA, Converter={StaticResource collectionViewFactoryConverter}, ConverterParameter=Row.Name}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Row.Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <!--Code below is working, but results are unsorted-->
    <!--<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="RootTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding RefA}">                                  
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Row.Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>-->

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ModelATemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding RefB}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Row.Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ModelBTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Row.Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>        

</Window.Resources>
```

Code of the TreelistControl:

```
    <dxgcore:TreeListControl Name="treeListControl"
        DesignTimeShowSampleData="False"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsRoot}}"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="123,0,0,0" ItemsSourceChanged="treeListControl_ItemsSourceChanged">

        <dxg:TreeListControl.View>
            <dxg:TreeListView Name="tlvList" 
            IsColumnMenuEnabled="False"
            AllowPerPixelScrolling="True"
            AutoWidth="True"
            ShowHorizontalLines="False" 
            ShowVerticalLines="False"
            ShowIndicator="False" 
            ShowFocusedRectangle="False" 
            NavigationStyle="Row"
            TreeLineStyle="Solid"                                  
            FixedLineWidth="1" 
            FilterEditorShowOperandTypeIcon="True" 
            DataRowTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}"
            TreeDerivationMode="HierarchicalDataTemplate"
            FocusedNode="{Binding HierarchicalFilterSelection, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
        >
            </dxg:TreeListView>
        </dxg:TreeListControl.View>
    </dxgcore:TreeListControl>
```

Converter Class:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(System.Collections.IList), typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable))]

public class CollectionViewFactoryConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        System.Collections.IList collection = (System.Collections.IList)value as System.Collections.IList;
        ListCollectionView view = new ListCollectionView(collection);
        SortDescription sort = new SortDescription(parameter.ToString(), ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        view.SortDescriptions.Add(sort);
        return view;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The template selector looks like this BTW:

```
public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        DataTemplate template = null;
        if (item != null)
        {
            FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;
            if (element != null)
            {

                string templateName = "StandardTemplate";
                DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.TreeList.TreeListRowData itemAsTreelistRowData = null;

                if (item is DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.TreeList.TreeListRowData)
                {
                    itemAsTreelistRowData = item as DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.TreeList.TreeListRowData;
                }

                if (itemAsTreelistRowData.Row is Root)
                {
                    templateName = "RootTemplate";
                }
                else
                    if (itemAsTreelistRowData.Row is ModelA)
                    {
                        templateName = "ModelATemplate";
                    }
                    else

                        if (itemAsTreelistRowData.Row is ModelB)
                        {
                            templateName = "ModelBTemplate";
                        }

                template = element.FindResource(templateName) as DataTemplate;
            }
        }
        return template;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see your converter being used anywhere.... I see you binding to a `TemplateSelector`, but no code to use the converter for your TreeListView

Comment: I've added the code of the TemplateSelector now. The actual HierarchicalDataTemplates are indeed triggered - if I change e.g. Row.Name to something else, I see the change. But the converter apparently fails to be called at this point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling the converter right in the binding for the ItemsSource in your TreeListControl:

```
  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsRoot}, Converter={StaticResource collectionViewFactoryConverter}}"
```

Comment: In this case the converter gets triggered, but I cannot sort children nodes with it now, I fear. I always need to sort the nodes of the next level (RefA, RefB etc.), so the Converter somehow needs to work at the various levels. And it steadfastly refuses to do so. :(

P.S. I've added the code of the TemplateSelector now, where it is decided which HierarchicalDataTemplate is picked. These templates are indeed triggered, but it looks like I cannot use a converter at this point.